# how to org-refile to a target within the current file?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-refile quite a bit, but for my use-case, I want to refile my org-mode subtrees not to an org-agenda file, but to the current file or another file I'm currently visiting.

I had a way of doing this that was working correctly, but now has stopped working. I'm not sure what I changed that broke it.

Here's the code I'm using for org-refile:

```
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil) ; Refile in a single go 
(setq org-completion-use-ido nil) 
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path t) ; Show full paths for refiling 
(setq org-refile-allow-creating-parent-nodes (quote confirm)) ; allow refile to create parent tasks with confirmation

(defun my-org-files-list ()
 (mapcar (lambda (buffer)
   (buffer-file-name buffer))
   (org-buffer-list 'files t))) 

(setq org-refile-targets '((my-org-files-list :maxlevel . 3)))
```

Again, this used to work. But now when I run org-refile, I get this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  get-file-buffer(nil)
  org-find-base-buffer-visiting(nil)
  org-get-agenda-file-buffer(nil)
  org-refile-get-targets(nil (#("this" 0 4 (fontified t face org-level-1))))
  org-refile-get-location("Refile subtree \"this\" to" nil confirm nil)
  org-refile(nil)
  call-interactively(org-refile record nil)
  command-execute(org-refile record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-refile")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eventual list of targets derived from the variable `org-refile-targets` by `org-refile-get-targets` needs to be valid buffers or files, or else `org-get-agenda-file-buffer` will complain when it uses `org-find-base-buffer-visiting`.  The original custom function `my-org-files-list` will return one or more `nil` entries in the list when there are non-file-visiting-buffers in `org-mode`.  The solution is to delete the `nil` entries from the list using `delq`.

```lisp
(defun my-org-files-list ()
  (delq nil
    (mapcar (lambda (buffer)
      (buffer-file-name buffer))
      (org-buffer-list 'files t))))
```